I'm trying to download Ubuntu Desktop 24.04 LTS and create a bootable USB using balenaetcher, but it's not working
I'm trying to download Ubuntu Desktop 24.04 LTS and create a bootable USB using balenaetcher, but it's not working.
help me :(




Does this answer your question? What is the proper way of creating installation media from Ubuntu iso?

Use Universal USB Installer instead.

Download it: https://pendrivelinux.com/downloads/Universal-USB-Installer/Universal-USB-Installer-2.0.2.3.exe
Choose an ISO



Click on create!


thank you a lot Archisman Panigrahi. i really afraid the virus because my level is hard to see even i get virus but i will believe you because you look kind.

It is a free and open source tool, and definitely not a virus. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_USB_Installer

I have tried balenaEtcher to create a bootable USB but several issues were faced. That's when I came across Ventoy.
Ventoy is an open-source tool to create bootable USB drives that support ISO/WIM/IMG/VHD(x)/EFI files with different Operating Systems. All you have to do is copy the image file and paste it onto the drive.

Download the Ventoy file from their Official Downloads link based on your current OS.

Format your USB drive and install Ventoy on it.


Copy-paste your desired ISO image (your Ubuntu Desktop 24.04 LTS) to the Ventoy partition.

Now restart your system and enter the boot menu. You will see a GUI to choose your ISO image to boot.



I have been using Ventoy for long and it works flawlessly for all the Ubuntu versions and Windows 10 and 11. I didn't have to burn a drive multiple times or keep another drive to install other versions of my distros.

Can someone explain the downvote?

I agree - (1) it’s discourteous to downvote without a comment, (2) I think it’s a useful answer.

Yeah Ventoy on a huge USB drive is a game changer!  I have Linux folders and windows folders and just copy my isos onto my ventoy drive to whatever dir i want.  Ventoy finds all the isos on the drive.  Easiest way ,by far, to create a windows installation usb drive from a Linux OS. And! I still use my ventoy USB drive to store and move other files as well. Ventoy just ignores files that aren't iso images.

I don’t think you’ve added anything not already said in  the more complete answer by Ajay?
